# When does the 15-day period start for H-1B visa petitions?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

In their website, USCIS says the following, regarding H-1B visa:

> USCIS provides premium processing service for certain employment-based petitions and guarantees a 15-calendar-day processing time.

But is it a 15-day period from what? From the day they receive the petition? The day they enter the petitioner's data into the system? The day they posted the receipt?

I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

[USCIS guarantees](http://www.uscis.gov/news/alerts/uscis-begin-premium-processing-h-1b-cap-subject-petitions-april-28-2014) that it will process all H1-B applications with premium processing within 15 calendar days of April 28th. So you should hear by May 13th at the latest. Good luck!

Comment: Can you provide a link to back that up? Not that we don't believe you, it's just useful for the site to have a reference.

Comment: @MarkMayo: sure, sorry. Here's the reference: http://www.uscis.gov/news/alerts/uscis-begin-premium-processing-h-1b-cap-subject-petitions-april-28-2014

Comment: Cool, thanks. Next time edit it into the answer - I've done it for you this time.  Have removed the post notice as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

15 days from the date printed on the receipt notice.

I have heard a few people Having delays in their premium processing applications past 15 days. So don't be surprised if it does.